# Adding JavaScript line into some code

Tags: javascript, html, encryption, blogger

I am trying to password protect some text in a Blogger blogpost and I found a website that explains how to do so.

I had to add this line of code between my `<head>` tags in the html template:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.vincentcheung.ca/jsencryption/jsencryption.js"></script>
```

And once that's done I just need to:

1. copy the text from the blogpost I want to password protect into their box here → http://www.vincentcheung.ca/jsencryption/
2. Type my password in their Key box
3. Copy the HTML code provided in their last box.

This is the basic code used in the body of the html code of my blogpost to do the decryption:

```
<div id="uniqueID" title="encrypted text">
    <a href="javascript:decryptText('uniqueID')">Show encrypted text</a>
</div>
```

And I can easily change the text "Show encrypted text" by anything else I like.

However, once people click in the 'Show encrypted text' link, a box pops out, with some text:

[image]

And I would like to change that and do not know how to do so, since I don't know any JavaScript at all.

In the instructions, it says:

You can change the message in the dialog box that asks for the key by providing the desired message as a second parameter, eg. *decryptText('uniqueID', 'Enter the password:')*

But I don't really know where to add it. I have tried, but nothing seems to work. 
Here is the website: http://www.vincentcheung.ca/jsencryption/instructions.html

Comment: *"I don't know any JavaScript at all"* - Perhaps you should invest some time to learn some JavaScript. After all, Stack Overflow is a site for programmers. At least you got the capitalization right, so you are already better than 60% of JavaScript developers.

Comment: Well, I am not a programmer. I am a blogger and decided to learn html and css becuase I thought I'd be useful and would help me, so I signed up here in case I ever needed help -- and now just used the opportunity to ask this question. I don't normally need to use JavaScript and frankly, I do not want to learn an entire programming language just because I might need it one day for my blog. Do you really learn everything you might need help at some point of your life? Because that might mean every proffesion and language it exists. So, perhaps, what you need to do is mind your own business

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this inserted in your page:

```
<a href="javascript:decryptText('uniqueID')">Show encrypted text</a>
```

Just add a second parameter to that function call with your custom question:

```
<a href="javascript:decryptText('uniqueID', 'Enter your passworld please.')">Show encrypted text</a>
```

Comment: Thanks I tried that Christoph, but now I got a weird error in the background of my blog (thankfully this is a test one). See here on the top left corner --> https://i.snag.gy/OKnyGP.jpg

I have deleted the blog post with the html/javascript, but I keep getting that weird error... So: 1) I do not know how to get rid of that, 2) I cannot use that on my actual blog since I get that error. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Looks like there is some character that's wrongly inserted. Like an additional `>` or `"`. Inside the `href="..."` you shouldn't use those characters without escaping them.

Comment: Okay, I got it working now Chris, thanks. Does something a bit weird though, it duplicates the blogpost but then one of them it's completely empty. This doesn't happen if I do not change that text/add that parameter. Do you know why this could be or how to avoid it?